# Workspace giving two different behaviors in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am learning about Cargo workspaces and have set up the following structure:

Top-level:

```
[package]
name = "workspacer"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ustulation <zzzzzz@gmail.com>"]

[workspace]
members = ["safe_core", "safe_authenticator", "safe_app"]

# If this is removed then each of the sub-projects will have thier own Cargo.lock file
# will build binaries/objects in their own target/ directories. With this present, it's
# always the parent-projects Cargo.lock and target/ directory used. Need to check if this
# is standard behaviour or some bug about to be fixed.
[lib]
crate_type = ["rlib", "cdylib", "staticlib"]
```

A lib called **safe_core** which only needs to produce a `.rlib`

```
[package]
authors = ["ustulation <zzzzzz@gmail.com>"]
name = "safe_core"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
maidsafe_utilities = "~0.10.0"
```

A lib called **safe_app** which depends on **safe_core** and needs to produce all 3 `.rlib`, `.a` and `.so`:

```
[package]
name = "safe_app"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ustulation <zzzzzz@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
maidsafe_utilities = "~0.10.0"
safe_core = { path = "../safe_core" }

[lib]
crate_type = ["rlib", "cdylib", "staticlib"]
```

A lib called **safe_authenticator** which depends on **safe_core** and needs to produce all 3 `.rlib`, `.a` and `.so`:

```
[package]
name = "safe_authenticator"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ustulation <zzzzzz@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
safe_core = { path = "../safe_core" }

[lib]
crate_type = ["rlib", "cdylib", "staticlib"]
```

The tree looks like:

```
workspacer
├── Cargo.toml
├── safe_app
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── safe_authenticator
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── safe_core
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

If I go to `safe_core` and build, it creates a `target/` folder and `Cargo.lock` files inside the top level `workspacer/`, which is good.

If I go to `safe_authenticator` folder and build that it too uses the same `target/` and `Cargo.lock` files and hence does not recompile `safe_core` which is what I want too. Same with `safe_app`.

However if I remove the `[lib]` section from the top-level `workspacer/Cargo.toml`, each of the sub-projects start creating their own `Cargo.lock` files and their own `/target` directories inside their respective sub-directories. I have mentioned this in the inline comment in the `Cargo.toml` of `workspacer` above (the 1st snippet above).

Is this an expected behavior or a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

```
~$ rustc --version && cargo --version
rustc 1.15.0-nightly (ba872f270 2016-11-17)
cargo 0.15.0-nightly (1877f59 2016-11-16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After confirming it on latest stable:

```
~$ rustc --version && cargo --version
rustc 1.13.0 (2c6933acc 2016-11-07)
cargo 0.13.0-nightly (eca9e15 2016-11-01)
```

It [seems to be a bug](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/workspace-giving-two-different-behaviors-in-rust/8385/3):

> All members of workspace should share the same target directory no
>   matter what!

A [bug report was submitted](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3407), and it is solved now.